# How to divide documents values into same document, however key name of the divisor is same in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

**Explanation**: want to divide the `name: Alex`  , `name: petr`   `value` by `name: hr`  `value`.

`name: Alex`  , `name: petr`  and `name: hr` are my parameters names.

also want to see the value of `name: hr` in the output document.

```
[
  {
    "name": "Alex",
    "value": 65
  },
  {
    "name": "petr",
    "value": 8
  },
  {
    "name": "hr",
    "value": 20  
}
]
```

**Expected Output** :

```
[
  {
    "name": "Alex/hr",
    "value": 3.25
  },
  {
    "name": "petr/hr",
    "value": 0.4
  },
  {
    "name": "hr",
    "value": 20  
}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/38G_Loo8V86

Use [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      hrVal: [
        { $match: { name: "hr" } }, // filter
        { $project: { _id: 0, value: 1 } } // take only value
      ],
      allValues: [] // all documents or you can add match pipeline to filter here
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$hrVal" }, //  break into individual documents - now every document will have hrVal.value
  { $unwind: "$allValues" }, //  break into individual documents
  {
    $set: { // 
      "allValues": {
        "$cond": [
          { $eq: [ "$allValues.name", "hr" ] }, // condition
          "$allValues",  // true
          { // false
           _id: "$allValues._id",
           name: { "$concat": [ "$allValues.name", "/hr" ] }, // set name
           value: { "$divide": [ "$allValues.value", "$hrVal.value" ] } // divide by hr value
         }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  { $replaceRoot: { "newRoot": "$allValues" } } // reset to orignal document shape
])
```

Comment: nice solution without lookup.

Comment: @turivishal Thank you bro, you did amazing work with lookup.

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar Thanks for the query, it is looking good, but I'm getting this error message "Command failed with error 2 (BadValue): 'sub-pipeline in $facet stage cannot be empty' on server".

Comment: @bc110402922 Try `allValues: [ { $match: {} } ]` https://mongoplayground.net/p/qzBCKLj8n83

Comment: thanks! it works now, But just a minor thing, after I just re-think my question, I don't need the value of `name: hr` in the output document. what line should I remove from the query?

Comment: @bc110402922 `allValues: [ { $match: { "name": { $ne: "hr" } } } ]` https://mongoplayground.net/p/AW4om0GcrHN you can get rid of `$cond` also. check the demo

Answer (score 2):

- `$lookup` with same collection and match for `name: hr` and return single result
- `$unwind` deconstruct `hr` array
- `$project` to check condition if `name` is hr then return current `name` and `value` of not then concat name using `$concat` and divide value by `$divide`
- `$project` to move `doc` object to root

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection",
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { name: "hr" } },
        { $limit: 1 }
      ],
      as: "hr"
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$hr" },
  {
    $project: {
      doc: {
        $cond: [
          { $eq: ["$name", "hr"] },
          {
            name: "$name",
            value: "$value"
          },
          {
            name: { $concat: ["$name","/","$hr.name"] },
            value: { $divide: ["$value", "$hr.value"] }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      name: "$doc.name",
      value: "$doc.value"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DlUYgPLbd_1)

---

Second option without lookup,

- `$facet` to separate both result
- `$map` to iterate loop of `result` array and check `name is hr` then concat `name` and divide `value` otherwise return same
- `$unwind` deconstruct `result` array
- `$project` to show fields

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      result: [{ $match: {} }],
      hr: [{ $match: { name: "hr" } }]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      result: {
        $map: {
          input: "$result",
          in: {
            $cond: [
              { $eq: ["$$this.name", "hr"] },
              "$$this",
              {
                name: { $concat: ["$$this.name", "/", { $first: "$hr.name" }] },
                value: { $divide: ["$$this.value", { $first: "$hr.value" }] }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$result" },
  {
    $project: {
      name: "$result.name",
      value: "$result.value"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eNGjEklX1BD)

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, the the `value` is not available in the collection `value` is also calculated in the same query, the lookup is not possible for me, can we go without lookup?

Comment: do you have any idea how I can accomplish this? 
[AggMonthYear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67620593/aggregation-on-month-level-and-year-level-also-find-the-average-in-mongodb)