# Aggregation on month level and year level, also find the average in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

**Explanation**: I want to find the average of the 2018,2021 and 2020 values. years and month will be pass using query parameters.
also, find the average on the month level if the complete year is not available, then the average could be on the month level, the month will be also passed from the query parameter.

From the query parameter, if the user gives months as a parameter, the result of the average is on the month level.
IF users give one year or multiple years aggregation will year level

Query parameters are as drop down

- Timebase selector (month, year)
- Year base selector 2018,2015,2016....
- Month base selector (all months, 12, 11,...08, ..03, 01)

---

if the explanation is not clear let me know, please. Thanks in advance.

```
    {
  "data": {
    "2018-05-11": {
      "12": 12.4,
      "00": 11.3
    },
    "2018-12-31": {
      "12": 12.4,
      "06": 13
    },
    "2021-05-10": {
      "00": 11.3,
      "06": 13
    },
    "2021-05-11": {
      "12": 12.4,
      "00": 11.3,
      "06": 13
    },
    "2021-05-13": {
      "12": 6,
      "06": 13
    },
    "2020-06-01": {
      "12": 3.4,
      "09": 1.8
    },
    "2020-06-15": {
      "12": 3.9,
      "09": 11.8
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i guess this is your expected result, can you show actual documents.. and query params example inputs..

Comment: Thanks for comment, yes, I can tell you, there is a drop-down list last 3 years, last 5 years, last 10 years, last 3 month last 6 month last 9 month, 
in my mind to use the MongoDB month and year aggregation, but not clear how to use on these values

Comment: still not clear, just add in your question what is the param and possible values, and also example document that you have in database,

Comment: Example document I already posted.  
`-` parameters are as drop down
`-`  Timebase selector (month, year)
`-` Year base selector 2018,2015,2016....
`-` Month base selector (all months, 12, 11,...08, ..03, 01)

Comment: is that `data` key available in collection?

Comment: no, we don't have `data` key, data is an object, in `data` we have dates, inside the date we have the values. we have to aggregate the values on month and year level but we have to define the keys. for month and year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$objectToArray` convert `data` object to array key-value format
- `$filter` to iterate loop of above converted array
- check `$and` conditions
- `$toDate` to get `data` from string date
- `$month` to select month from date and `$year` to select year
- `$in` check in condition if month is in array of months and year is in array of years
- `$arrayToObject` convert back to object from key-value array

```
var years = [2021];
var months = [5];
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      data: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $filter: {
            input: { $objectToArray: "$data" },
            cond: {
              $and: [
                { $in: [{ $year: { $toDate: "$$this.k" } }, years] },
                { $in: [{ $month: { $toDate: "$$this.k" } }, months] }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/k-QB_SqQVVO)

Comment: But where is the average of the values for year 2021?

Comment: I just change the little bit data structure, can you check it now?
[dateHoursAsKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67624735/convert-array-into-key-as-a-complete-time-and-value-in-mongodb) Thanks!