# convert array into key as a complete time and value in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

**Explanation**: in `b` we have hours, and have to complete the time and concatenate with a date. then complete date and time become as key. please see the expected outout

```
{
  "code": [
    {
      "a": "2016-05-10",
      "b": {
        "12": 1,
        "00": 2,
        "06": 3
      }
    },
    {
      "a": "2017-12-31",
      "b": {
        "12": 4,
        "00": 5,
        "06": 6
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
 "code": {
    "2016-05-10T12:00:00:0Z": 1,
    "2016-05-10T00:00:00:0Z": 2,
    "2016-05-10T06:00:00:0Z": 3,
    "2017-12-31T12:00:00:0Z": 4,
    "2017-12-31T00:00:00:0Z": 5,
    "2017-12-31T06:00:00:0Z": 6
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$concat` to concat parts of the date
- `$reduce` to iterate loop of code array and concat above processed array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      code: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $reduce: {
            input: "$code",
            initialValue: [],
            in: {
              $concatArrays: [
                "$$value",
                {
                  $map: {
                    input: { $objectToArray: "$$this.b" },
                    as: "b",
                    in: {
                      k: {
                        $concat: ["$$this.a", "T", "$$b.k", ":00:00:0Z"]
                      },
                      v: "$$b.v"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1REt16rTkDg)

Comment: Thanks.. somehow its working, but getting the error message 
 'Error parsing date string '2016-05-10T00:00:00.000Z'; 19: Format literal not found '.'' on server .

Comment: i am not sure but this is not good idea to set date as key name, because there are some limitation on key name in some cases it will not allow dot `.`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, the expected out the key is ended with  `0Z`, can we format it? it and **PlaygroundOutput** key ended with  `000Z`

Comment: it is millisecond with timezone so its hidden by date type `ISODate("2016-05-10T12:00:00Z")` but whenever we convert it to string it will return with `"2016-05-10T12:00:00.000Z"`..

Comment: i have updated the answer with new approach, hope it will work..

Comment: [:000ZSol](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WgZAqBQCy4g)

Comment: Thanks, Its clear and i get the answer, can you check please this problem.
[AggergationPerYearPerMonth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67636505/aggregation-per-year-and-month-in-mongodb)
Thanks in advance