# Aggregation per year and month in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

**Explanation**: I have an Array name as code, I have query parameters name as  `year`(drop-down list 2016,2017,2018,2019,....) and `month` drop-down list as (**ALL**,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12).

CASE1: If the user selects a specific year and specific month get the `code` array accordingly.

CASE2: If the user selects the specific year and from month **ALL**, get the `code` array complete year.

```
{
  "code":[
    {
      "k": "2016-06-18T18",
      "v": 1
    },
    {
      "k": "2016-06-18T21",
      "v": 2
    },
    {
      "k": "2016-07-19T00",
      "v": 13
    },
    {
      "k": "2015-06-19T03",
      "v": 6
    },
    {
      "k": "2015-07-19T06",
      "v": 6
    }
  ]
}
```

**CASE 1 Expected Output IF user-selected** : From year drop-down : 2016 , month : 06

```
{
  "code":[
    {
      "k": "2016-06-18T18",
      "v": 1
    },
    {
      "k": "2016-06-18T21",
      "v": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

**CASE 2 Expected Output IF user-selected** : From year drop-down : 2016 , month : **ALL**.

```
{
  "code":[
    {
      "k": "2016-06-18T18",
      "v": 1
    },
    {
      "k": "2016-06-18T21",
      "v": 2
    },
    {
      "k": "2016-07-19T00",
      "v": 13
    },
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- initialize request params

```
var year = req.year;
var month = req.month;
```

- set default year condition

```
var condition = [{
  $eq: [{ $substr: ["$$this.k", 0, 4] }, String(year)]
}];
```

- check if month is available and not all then add condition

```
if (month && month != "all") {
  condition.push({
    $eq: [{ $substr: ["$$this.k", 5, 2] }, String(month)] 
  });
}
```

- `$filter` to iterate loop of code and filter above prepared conditions

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      code: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$code",
          cond: { $and: condition }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KwpWJHXvC1g)

Comment: Thank you explanation is really great, but can you make a query in one block, I did not get how you are setting the If `condition `.

Comment: CASE 1, is working fine, but CASE 2 is not working properly for me.

Comment: it is in sequence you can just put it in sequence, for second case verify your if condition, replace "all" with your value that your passing when it select all.. and try to pass month in string like "01", "02" ...

Comment: try to console `condition` field before query and after if condition, and show actual condition with values..

Comment: Sorry, I did not get the idea., The `condition` is not working properly for me, I am using <#FREEMARKER> to making the if  `condition`. [FREEMARKER](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/search-results.html?q=if)
could you please set it according to <#FreeMarker>? or elaborate.
Thanks!

Comment: i don't know about FREEMARKER, if you know JS and FREEMARKER then it would be easy for you to convert.